# Migradoc: Adding pagebreaks when within certain distance of end of page

Tags: c#, migradoc

I'm trying to generate a report using Migradoc. The general generation of the PDF is working fine, however there are cases within the document where I sometimes end up with the start of a paragraph at the end of the page, then the body of the paragraph on the next page. This means that the bold text serving as the title within the paragraph appears at the end of the page but the body appears on the next one.

I know I could add a page break prior to the start of the paragraph, but it's equally possible that it starts nearer the start of the page so doing this would also result in some cases in a broken layout.

Is it possible to determine the distance from the end of the page when adding a paragraph so that I can decide at that point whether a page break is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages do not exist yet when you create a MigraDoc document, so you cannot determine on which page an item will be or where on a page.

You can set the property `Format.KeepTogether` of the `Paragraph` to `true` to prevent page breaks within the paragraph.

If the bold heading is a separate paragraph, then you can set the property `Format.KeepWithNext` of the `Paragraph` to `true` to prevent page breaks between this paragraph and the next one. This could be the better approach if the paragraph has a long body.